# jQuery acting weird

Tags: jquery, html

So, I wrote a small page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  

    <script>  
       function slide() {  
          $("#d").slideUp("slow");  
          document.getElementById("d").innerHTML=Math.random();  
          $("#d").slideDown("slow");  
       }   
    </script>  

  </head>  
  <body>  

    <div id="d"></div>  
    <button onClick="slide()">do</button>  

  </body>  
</html>
```

And I don't know why but the text inside `div` is changed before the `$("#d").slideDown("slow")`, right when the `slideUp` begins.
I want it to work so that first `#d` `slideUp`, then while its height is close to 0 or something the innerHTML will change, and only after that `slideDown`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
function slide() {  
  $("#d").slideUp("slow", function() {
     $(this).html(Math.random).slideDown("slow");  
  });       
}
```

Here, the code inside the callback function gets called **after** the animation is completed. In your original code, this is not the case. The animation gets started and immediately after that the content gets changed.

Read the documentation about [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

**Update:**

Btw. `document.getElementById` is the same as `$('#id')` in jQuery. You can use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function. No need to look for the same element twice. And the element being animated is available in the callback function via `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, why don't you really use it?

```
$('#btnid').click(function() {
  $("#d").slideUp("slow");  
          $('#d').html(Math.random());  
          $("#d").slideDown("slow"); 
});
```

Just some improvement to your code

Comment: You did solve his problem, no? So why repeating what you have already done. I'm just enhancing his code by taking full advantages of the jQuery functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

First of all since you are using jQuery try [changing the contents of #d using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).
Also, if you need the content change to happen when slideUp finishes, you need to do that inside a callback function inside [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways...

or using Queue or Slide Callback function

> http://jsbin.com/otise/edit